# Will you clear my code to me. I just copied and pasted it and it worked as I wished?

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and I cannot under stand that what this mean.
I have written the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function(){
// Actually I have problem here:
$('#text').keyup(function(){
$('#cc').html($(this).val());
});
});
</script>
<input type="text" name="" id="text">
<div id="cc"></div>
</body>
<style type="text/css">
#cc{
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
border: 1px solid black;
text-overflow: all;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
</html>
```

I have problem here:

```
 $('#text').keyup(function(){
 $('#cc').html($(this).val());
 });
```

please tell me that what this anonymous function do and how?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on `keyup` and `html`?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: Actually keyup is not the problem. The problem is $('#cc').html($(this).val());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me clear before you

- **keyup** means when a key is pressed on keyboard and you pull your finger back the keyup function is triggered this is keyup functionality in jquery
- **#cc** is the an empty html element which is getting data from the id **#text** which is actually a input with the values we entered
- if you are confuse regarding **this** keyword then kepp it in mind this
  always represents the object which we are using with keyup function
  that is  **#text**

Comment: answer will be consider accepted when you will click up arrow on left side of my answer please do it

Comment: Oh I really didn't knew about that

Answer (score 0):

it says: On element with id #text if u release a key on your keyboard it wil change the HTML of an alement with ID #cc to the value of element #text.

Looking at the code, you can fill in text in the inputfield, and on every keypress you release it sets the same input to a div.

If you would like to research the code yourself, you could easily console log the values:

```
$().ready(function(){
// Actually I have problem here:
$('#text').keyup(function(){
 console.log($(this));//GIVE U BACK THE ELEMENT $(this), in this case its the inputfield #text.
 console.log($(this.val());//GIVE U BACK THE ELEMENTS VALUE, So the text in the input field
$('#cc').html($(this).val());
});
});
```

On keypress in the input field it wil now console log what you want to know. Press F12 in your browser and watch the console.